# Android Studio debugger copy value of array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, base64

I have a Base64-encoded key, as an input String, from which I want to create a new byte array using the decode method. I want to copy the resulting bytes to my notepad. I put a breakpoint and I execute the code in the debugger and everything work as they should. The array size is 392. I want to copy to the clipboard the value of the inputbytes array, so I right click on the bytes array, select "Copy Value" and then I paste it on a Notepad, but nothing is pasted. It seems that the value of the array cannot be copied. What am I doing wrong? How can I copy the value of the array?

```
String input ="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";
byte[] inputbytes = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

[image]

Android Studio 2.3.3

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems, that you cannot just copy arrays. Only single values.

While at the breakpoint, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>. That opens `Evaluate expression` pop-up. Enter there the following code:

```
Arrays.toString(inputBytes)
```

That will give the output of string formatted like the following:

```
[97, 115, 100]
```

[image]

From there you can manipulate with `.replace*` methods of the `String` class to remove the commas and the brackets. Or just use your text-editor.

Good luck :)

Comment: This workaround allowed me to copy the value of the array and complete my task. Upvoted for pointing out an alternative way, clearly. But they should have grayed out the "Copy Value" option if it isn't meant to work on arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hovering on the array or object you want to copy, a window will appear. At the bottom left there is **Create renderer** button,  where you can display/copy the array as your custom format.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customizing-views.html#renderers